# Add column to dataframe from other dataframe based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

I want to add a column from another dataframe to my main dataframe based on the timestamps.

My first dataframe looks like:

[image: df1]

Second dataframe looks like:

[image: df2]

I want to round off the timestamps of the second dataframe to minutes and then add the column 'Signal' to the first dataframe based on the timestamps.

So the result would look like this (the signal should only be "1" for the given timestamps):

[image: df3]

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be searched or copied and offer poor usability. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself, it is shown below

```
df1['timestamp'] = df1['timestamp'].values.astype('<M8[m]')
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'].values.astype('<M8[m]')

df3 = df2.sort_values('timestamp')

result = pd.merge_asof(df1,df3, on='timestamp', by='timestamp')
```